# How do I make Cloud Build Triggers show up with names on GitHub?

Tags: google-cloud-build

In description of Google Cloud Build app on GitHub here https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build every build seems to be identifiable by name:
[Cloud Build Triggers With Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uYC0.png)

In my current set up, however, every build is displayed by id, which is not very useful:

[Cloud Build Triggers with IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co608.png)

Is there something I am not doing to make it work as expected?

Comment: any news on how to do so? Thanks

Comment: @nerotulip no =(

Comment: When I configured things initially, I could see trigger names in PRs. Then after updating triggers I now see trigger IDs </3. I don't have permissions to play around, but I guess what I'd try is to reconnect GCB with GH in hopes things might revert back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

When I think about Cloud Builds, I understand that every individual build has a unique identifier.  For me, this is what I would want to see in a report of a build being triggered.  Given a Cloud Build ID, I can then use that for visibility into the underlying process that unique instance of the build caused.  I can see all the steps and the outcome of each of them.  I couldn't imagine wanting anything else than a build identifier being reported to me as a result of a Cloud Build being performed.

References:

- [Viewing build results](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results)

Comment: @zhendalf as you can see on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results#filtering_build_results_using_queries) when using Cloud Build there is no "name" field as you suggest. There are only "build_id" or "trigger_id" fields. And you current set up is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the original issue in the issuetracker in January 2020,

This is not since fixed and identified real names since August 17th. You do have to reclick on the new names if you have made any previous hash based ones required steps in your build.

Answer (score 0):

For any triggers created prior to August 2020, data sharing needs to be enabled for this to work, As documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers#data_sharing

You need to go in the Settings -> Data Sharing section of cloud build and enable it

[image: Data sharing config]

In some cases you might get a `Failed to enable trigger data sharing` error when trying to do this, if so you might want to try

1 - Disable any required checks you have in github related to cloud build

2 - Try doing it using chrome without any ad blocker, for me it wasn't working using Brave browser but worked with chrome

This will allow github to show the trigger name instead of an id in the pull request checks